# Is there a way to check if string or substring value from one column in a dataframe exists another column in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to compare two similar columns from two different excel sheets using python,

```
df1['CrowdStrike'] = np.where(df1['VM'].isin(df2['VM']), 'YES', 'NO')
```

it then populates a column to say if it exists, but is there a way to find substrings as well?

Comment: Perhaps replace `df1['VM'].isin...` with `df1['VM'].str.contains...`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I think that wouldn't work because I'm trying to compare the two columns and not look for one exact value? When I try it I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`

Comment: Apologies, I missed a step. What about `...df1['VM'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['VM']))...`

Comment: @G.Anderson is there a way that it can compare the two ignoring case? some of the values are uppercase in one excel sheet and lowercase in the other

Comment: @tristan.howard you can probably use the `flags` arg https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html